# In a graphite cluster, how carbon-relay (consistent hashing) chose which carbon-relay is the responsible to write a given metric

Tags: distributed, graphite

Let's suppose we have a cluster of 4 **carbon-relay** (*repl. 2, consistent hash*). In front of them we have a load balancer (least connections).

```
       [LB] 
---------|-------------
[s0] [s1] [s2] [s3]
```

I would like to know what policy **carbon-relay** uses to chose which node is the one to "write down" that metric?

Is it consistent, based on metric namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It runs a hash function on the metric name and selects the node from the ring, all this in a consistent hash style.